# Is it ok if the framework has inbuilt database?

Tags: ios, database, entity-framework, architecture, sdk

Me and one fellow developer are working on a iOS framework and we are in a debatable situation. I will try to explain it in more details below

**Questions**: Is it a good practice to bundle the database in the framework, instead of allowing developer using our developed framework to implement the local database of his own.

**My argument**: We should never bundle the database within the framework and we should allow user to implement the local database of his own so that perform different operations in the app as per his/her convenience. We should never force the developer to be dependent on the database and database structure we created for various tasks such as caching or offline storage. As a framework provider what we should provide is a base using which he can access functionality provided by our platform.

**His argument**: The database should be bundled in the framework itself so that developer can directly implement the front end of the app instead of managing database and its architecture. It doesn't matter if he want to use our database or not. If he doesn't want to use anything he will simply ignore it.

I would like to know which is a correct approach for designing a SDK/framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple databases, the fact that a framework has a database doesn't mean that the app that using the framework can't have a database and that shouldn't be a consideration for the framework.
If your framework can offer database or caching capabilities as an option then great , and if someone thinks that he can manage database better then your framework can and wants to do it by himself then also great.
I would think how can the framework suggest local database as an optional feature of the framework.